# How to change the orange hot corner theme to green, if I don't want to use Yaru-olive?

Tags: gnome, themes, customization, 22.04, gnome-tweaks

I changed the GTK theme to **Orchis-green-dark**, I have an orange theme when pressing ctrl to find my pointer, or at this activities hot corner: [image]

And I want to make them green, like in Yaru-olive, but I want to use Orchis.

But if I change the setting to green in the settings app, it will reset the GTK theme.

Comment: You are indicating in the tags you use 22.04. That version has the option to change accent colors. Is that not helping?

Comment: If I change it, it changes the GTK theme back to Yaru-olive, but I want to use Orchis-green-dark.

Comment: O yes, I see. Indeed, that accent color change is quite sophisticated in that it also changes application icons and gnome shell theme. Perhaps include this comment in your question so people are more aware of the specific issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself:

Install *User Themes* GNOME extension,

open gnome-tweaks change the *Legacy applications* entry to Orchis-green-dark,

and the *Shell* to Yaru-olive-dark. It was much easier than I thought!